# Sitecore 9.0 Update-1 JSS create sample app throw error : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.X.X.117:443

Tags: jss

I have Sitecore 9.0 update -1 version and followed (https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install) to setup JSS server.

Finally I can test my component like below and its working.

[image]

I tried to setup basic sitecore react JSS app using this(https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/quick-start).

I can install JSS client but I can't install sample react app.

Error below,

[image]

I tried setting up proxy for npm. Nothing will get work.

How can we resolve this error or how we can trouble shoot.

Comment: Everything looks like it is setup ok on the server. The error you're getting `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` would indicate there's a potential issue with your network connection. Is your computer behind a firewall/proxy that is blocking access to GitHub? Specifically, you need to be able to access `https://api.github.com` and `https://github.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the hint "@Adam Webar" proxy is the issue here.

below things i try to resolve finally,

1. clear npm,git caches.
2. clear git windows credentails in credential manager.
3. Important below is enabling proxy for npm,git and system variables like below from command prompt.

**[Enable npm proxy]**

- npm config set proxy=http://UserName:Password@proxy.com:portno/ -g
- npm config set https-proxy=http://UserName:Password@proxy.com:portno/
  -g

**[Enable git proxy]**

- git config --global http.proxy http://UserName:Password@proxy.com:portno/
- git config --global https.proxy http://UserName:Password@proxy.com:portno/

**[Enable system variabel proxy]**

- set HTTPS_PROXY=http://UserName:Password@proxy.com:portno/
- set HTTP_PROXY=http://UserName:Password@proxy.com:portno/